# Routing not working in a react app with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router-dom

I'm trying to create a `react` app with `webpack` which has some routing as well.

```
 "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
```

The routing works but when I go to a specific route and reload the page, it gives an error *cannot get /about*

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/users">
            <Users />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return <h2>Home</h2>;
}

function About() {
  return <h2>About</h2>;
}

function Users() {
  return <h2>Users</h2>;
}
```

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44805562/how-to-configure-webpack-dev-server-with-react-router-dom-v4) answer, adding

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  }
```

fixes the issue when its being run locally, but as soon as I deploy it, I get the same error

Comment: If you don't have your own server where you can specify how to handle get requests to your routes, you should use the hash router https://reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter.

Comment: sounds like you just need to route all requests to /index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your server does not know what to do when it is hit by the `/about` route, initially when the browser has no asset files (HTML, JS, etc.). It occurs only when you are at `/about` and you refresh the page.

React router is a client side router, and hence the browser needs to load the client assets completely before it can work on your routes.

All you need to do is to configure your server to give all your assets to client even if it hit by an unknown route. i.e. when the 404 (Not found) situation arises at the server, your server should still provide all the assets that would otherwise be delivered when the route is at `/`.

And your react router should handle the 404 (Not found) event at the client side. as follows,

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/about">
        <About />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/users">
        <Users />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Home />
      </Route>
      <Route path="*">
        <h2>Page Not Found</h2>
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </div>
</Router>
```

Please remember that, if you want to nest the routes then remove the `exact` property from the parent `Route`.

Comment: Makes complete sense, I was using IIS and had to make a couple of changes in the web. config file so no matter which route I want go to, the first thing to load is index.html which gets me all the assets needed.

Comment: This goes for app by create-react-app as well